# How can I associate and edit a column of tableview with a value from an array in java fx?

Tags: javafx

I want to create a table in a JavaFX application, 
so i create a class that defines the data model and provides methods and fields to further work with the table. 
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Item {
   private final SimpleStringProperty id;
   private final SimpleStringProperty serial_number ;
   private final SimpleStringProperty description;
   private final BooleanProperty check;
   private final IntegerProperty language;
   private final SimpleStringProperty cpvCode=new SimpleStringProperty("");
   private final SimpleStringProperty replaceItem=new SimpleStringProperty("");
   private final SimpleStringProperty includeInContract=new SimpleStringProperty("");
   private final List<Attribute> listOfAttrs=new ArrayList(); 




    public Item(String id1,String num,String des,Boolean bool,int lang) {
        this.description = new SimpleStringProperty(des);
        this.id = new SimpleStringProperty(id1);
        this.serial_number= new SimpleStringProperty(num);
        this.check=new SimpleBooleanProperty(bool);
        this.language=new SimpleIntegerProperty(lang);
        this.listOfAttrs.add(new Attribute("Yoo"));

    }

    public StringProperty cpvCodeProperty() {
        return cpvCode;
    }
    public StringProperty replaceItemProperty() {
        return replaceItem;
    }
    public StringProperty includeInContractProperty() {
        return includeInContract;
    }
    public IntegerProperty languageProperty(){
        return language;
    }
    public BooleanProperty checkProperty(){
        return check;
    }
    public StringProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public StringProperty serial_numberProperty() {
        return serial_number;
    }

    public StringProperty descriptionProperty() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setLanguage(int lang){
        this.language.set(lang);
    }
    public void setId(String fid) {
        this.id.set(fid);
    }

    public void setSerial_number(String fnumber) {
        this.serial_number.set(fnumber);
    }

    public void setDescription(String fdesc) {
        this.description.set(fdesc);
    }

    public void setCheck(Boolean checking) {
        this.check.set(checking);
    }

    public void setCpvCode(String cpv) {
        this.cpvCode.set(cpv);
    }
    public void setReplaceItem(String replace) {
        this.replaceItem.set(replace);
    }
    public void setIncludeInContract(String include) {
        this.includeInContract.set(include);
    }
    public synchronized void setListOfAttrs(Attribute attrs) {

        listOfAttrs.add(attrs);
    }

    public synchronized StringProperty getListOfAttrs(int index) {

        return listOfAttrs.get(index).nameCodeProperty();
    }


}
```

I have also created a tableview with scene builder

```
<AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #F0F0F0;">
    <children>
        <TableView fx:id="tableForItems" editable="true" pickOnBounds="true" prefHeight="463.0" prefWidth="901.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="129.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="41.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="55.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="33.0" text="Id" fx:id="tID" />
                <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="82.0" style="&#10;&#10;.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled .invalid-table-cell:selected:focused {&#10;    /* Works! */&#10;}&#10;&#10;.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled .invalid-table-cell:focused:selected:hover {&#10;    /* Works! */&#10;}" text="%prompt.column.item.serial.number" fx:id="tSer" />
                <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="105.0" text="%prompt.column.item.description" fx:id="tDes" />
                <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="121.0" text="%prompt.column.item.keywords" fx:id="checkId" />
                <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="%prompt.column.item.url" fx:id="langId" />
                <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="71.0" text="%prompt.column.item.cpv" fx:id="cpvId" />
                <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="131.0" text="%prompt.column.item.replacesItem" fx:id="replaceItem" />
                <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="155.0" text="%prompt.column.item.includedInContract" fx:id="includedInContract" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I have associated the data with the table columns.

```
tID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("id"));
tDes.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("description"));
tSer.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("serial_number"));
checkId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("check"));
langId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("language"));
cpvId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("cpvCode"));
replaceItem.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("replaceItem"));
```

i want to associate a column with the first value from the arraylist listOfAttrs. I did that :

```
lastNameCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Item,String>, TableCell<Item,String>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
        return new TableCell() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (this.getTableRow() != null && item != null) {
                    Item current =(Item) this.getTableRow().getItem();
                    String s=current.getListOfAttrs(0).getValue();
                    setText(s);

                } 
                else {
                    setText("");
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
lastNameCol.setEditable(true);
lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
    new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Item, String>>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Item, String> t) {
        ((Item) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setListOfAttrs(new Attribute(t.getNewValue()));
    }
});
```

and I have in column the first value but I cannot edit the column or it doesn't change if I change the value in the arraylist. Could someone help me?

Comment: Try using an ObservableList instead of List.  I haven't tested it but I think that's the theory.  `private final ObservableList<Attribute> listOfAttrs=FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

Comment: I used ObservableList but nothing changed.

Comment: I don't see where you assign a list of items to your TableView.  Do you have an ObservableList<Item> somewhere?  I just see the class defined in your code.  As far as I can tell from the code there's not data put into your TableView.  You do that in the constructor or .setItems(an observable list of items).  After that's working, if it is, then you watch for changes in listOfAttrs.

Comment: i want from a list which is created into the constructor of class Items to show the first element into a cell and to have the possibility to edit this cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot I don't understand in your code as some is missing.  You should make the simplest possible example of something that runs and shows the problem.  I copied chunks of your code and added some stuff needed to make it work.  Now you have the nested list structure and the table responds to changes in the list and to edits.

package table;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Table extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<Item> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("add ids");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                items.addAll(new Item("id1"), new Item("id2"));
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        TableColumn tID = new TableColumn("ID");
        tID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("id"));

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("last name");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Item, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Item, String> p) {
                return p.getValue().getListOfAttrs();
            }
        });

        lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Item, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Item, String> t) {
                ((Item) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setListOfAttrs(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });

    TableView tv = new TableView(items);

        tv.setEditable(true);
        tv.getColumns().addAll(tID, lastNameCol);
        root.getChildren().add(tv);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Nested Obs list test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
}

public class Item {

    private final SimpleStringProperty id;
    private final ObservableList<Attribute> listOfAttrs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public Item(String id1) {
        this.id = new SimpleStringProperty(id1);
        this.listOfAttrs.add(new Attribute("Yoo " + id1));
    }

    public StringProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String fid) {
        this.id.set(fid);
    }

    public synchronized void setListOfAttrs(String attrs) {
        listOfAttrs.get(0).nameCode.set(attrs);
    }

    public synchronized StringProperty getListOfAttrs() {
        return listOfAttrs.get(0).nameCodeProperty();
    }

}

public class Attribute {

    private SimpleStringProperty nameCode;

    public Attribute(String s) {
        this.nameCode = new SimpleStringProperty(s);
    }

    public StringProperty nameCodeProperty() {
        return nameCode;
    }


}
}
```